# I can not find where the code decides to Change the value of Slot2 from R to Y.

Tags: c#

in context the program looks for the first slot "Slot1 = "Y" then it checks the spaces orthogonal to Slot1 to find if they are the second slot "Slot2 = "R". 
     Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Rose_Game;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Net;

namespace Rose_Game
{
    class MainClass
    {


        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //testing this
            string[,] board = new string[4, 4];


            board[0, 0] = "W";
            board[0, 1] = "W";
            board[0, 2] = "W";
            board[0, 3] = "W";
            board[1, 0] = null;
            board[1, 1] = "W";
            board[1, 2] = "P";
            board[1, 3] = "W";
            board[2, 0] = "W";
            board[2, 1] = "Y";
            board[2, 2] = "R";
            board[2, 3] = "W";
            board[3, 0] = "W";
            board[3, 1] = "P";
            board[3, 2] = "R";
            board[3, 3] = "W";
here you see that Slot2 is R
            string Slot1 = "Y";
            string Slot2 = "R";

            //end of testing
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;


            Positions.Pos1(Slot1,Slot2,board,x,y);

        }
    }
}
```

this is  Positions.cs

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
namespace Rose_Game
{
    public class Positions
    {
        public Positions()
        {
        }

        public static void Pos1(string Slot1, string Slot2, string[,] board,int x, int y)
        {
            int ans = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Slot1 is {0}",Slot1);
            Console.WriteLine("Slot2 is {0}",Slot2);

            for (int b = 0; b < 4; b++)
            {
                if (y+b<4 && board[x, y + b] == Slot1)
                    {
                        ans = 1;
                        y = y + b;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (y + b < 4 && x + 1 < 4 && board[x + 1, y + b] == Slot1)
                    {
                        ans = 1;
                        y = y + b;
                        x = x + 1;
                        break;                      
                    }

                    else if (y + b < 4 && x + 2 < 4 && board[x + 2, y + b] == Slot1)
                    {
                        ans = 1;
                        y = y + b;
                        x = x + 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if ( y + b < 4 && x + 3 < 4 && board[x + 3, y + b] == Slot1)
                    {
                        ans = 1;
                        y = y + b;
                        x = x + 3;
                        break;
                    }
                }


            switch (ans)
            {
                case 1:
                    Pos2(board,Slot1, Slot2, x, y);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Slot1 {0} = ({1},{2})", Slot1, x, y);
                    Console.WriteLine("Card did not Score");
                    break;
            }





        }

        public static void Pos2(string[,] board, string Slot2,string Slot1, int x, int y)
        {
            int ans = 0;
```

somewhere before this Slot2 changes to Y:
                Console.WriteLine(board[2,2]);
                Console.WriteLine("Slot2 is {0}",Slot2);

```
                if (y + 1 < 4 && board[x, y + 1] == Slot2)
                {
                    ans = 2;
                    y = y + 1;
                }

                else if (y - 1 < 0 && board[x, y - 1] == Slot2)
                {
                    ans = 2;
                    y = y - 1;
                }

                else if (x + 1 < 4 && board[x + 1, y] == Slot2)
                {
                    ans = 2;
                    x = x + 1;
                }

                else if (x - 1 > 0 && board[x - 1, y] == Slot2)
                {
                    ans = 2;
                    x = x - 1;
                }
                else 
                {
                    ans = 3;

                }





                switch (ans)
                {
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine(" Slot2 {0} = ({1},{2})", Slot2, x, y);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("The card  did not scored");
                    break;

                    default:
                        Pos1(Slot1,Slot2,board,x,y);
                        break;
                }

            }


    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. You are passing in the `pos1`s `Slot1` into `pos2` as `Slot2` and then printing that out. Nothing has changed at all.

Comment: Also the correct tool to solve such issues is your debugger.

Comment: thanks for the info I just figured it out. for some reason `public static void Pos2(string[,] board, string Slot2,string Slot1, int x, int y)` I needed to switch the Slot1 and Slot2 positions to `public static void Pos2(string[,] board, string Slot1,string Slot2, int x, int y)` I can't understand why the order messed things up

Comment: When you post code here, make sure all code is formatted correctly and I strongly suggest removing extra blank lines to reduce scrolling.

Comment: I will keep that in mind